# date column is populating as null in pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

I am using the below query to cast the `DATE_Landing` column. The entries for the `DATE_Landing` column are as below.

```
DATE_Landing
2021-04-28 00:00:00.0
```

Expected output:

```
DATE
2021-04-28
```

The query I tried

```
final_query_RAW = spark.sql("select sum(salary) as salary, replace(DATE_Landing,' 00:00:00.0','') as DATE from empytable group by DATE_Landing").withColumn('DATE',(unix_timestamp(col('DATE_Landing'), 'dd-MM-yyyy').cast("Timestamp")))
```

when I use the above query I get the values for Date_landing as null.

Could you please help I resolving the above challenge

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: How about something like `SELECT Format(CAST(DATE_Landing AS date), 'yyyy-MM-dd')`

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it has helped me resolve the challenge